# When n is odd, an even map $S^n\rightarrow S^n$ always has even degree.

Tags: algebraic-topology

If $f$ is an even map $S^n$ to $S^n$ then this induces an map
$S^n$ to $RP^n$ to $ S^n$
Also when n is odd we have that $H_n(RP^n)$ is isomorphic to $H_n(RP^n/RP^{n-1})$.

I would like to use this to prove that the degree of $f$ is even.

I do not know where to go from there.

Comment: Hint: Take your first sentence and use $H_n(\cdot,\Bbb Z_2)$.